# Django setting - apps aren't loaded yet

Tags: django, django-models, django-settings, django-push-notifications

I want to import an apps model in setting.py for PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS_SETTINGS in [django-push-notifications](https://github.com/jleclanche/django-push-notifications). This is my code:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ....
    'my_app',
    'push_notifications'
    ....
)

from my_app.models import User

PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS_SETTINGS = {
    'GCM_API_KEY': 'xxxxx',
    'APNS_CERTIFICATE': 'xxxxx.pem',
    'USER_MODEL': User,  # i want to change the default from auth_user to my_app User
}
```

But it raise an error on this line:

```
from my_app.models import User
```

The error is:

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

How Can i load my_app model in setting.py?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot load models from inside your settings file like that - models can only be loaded once all apps are loaded (which can only happen after the settings have been loaded).

Looking at the code in `django-push-notifications`, you should be able to provide the model as a string with dotted path:

```
'USER_MODEL': 'my_app.User'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't load User model in settings, but instead you can change it

```
PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS_SETTINGS = {
    'GCM_API_KEY': 'xxxxx',
    'APNS_CERTIFICATE': 'xxxxx.pem',
    'USER_MODEL': 'my_app.User',  
}
```

And use it later like:

```
from django.apps import apps
from django.conf import settings
User = apps.get_model(settings.PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS_SETTINGS['USER_MODEL'])
```

And you can do whatever you want with this User model